# Remove all event listeners of a Backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Is there a way to remove all event listens instantiated by a backbone view? For example, suppose I have the following HTML/JavaScript. When #box is clicked, I want a pop-up to say hello.

```
<div id="box" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: red"></div>

var Listener = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#box",
    events:  {
        'click #box' : 'hello'
    },
    hello: function () {
        alert('hello!');
    }
})

var listener = new Listener();
```

Now, I want to remove the event listener. Setting listener to something else doesn't work:

```
listener = ''; // doesn't work
```

How do I remove the event listener?

Comment: May be you can have a look at [an article](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/) by [Derick Bailey](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/author/derickbailey/).

Answer (score 14):

Anywhere in your View:

```
this.undelegateEvents();
```

You can then manually rebind events at a later time with `delegateEvents();`

- http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents
- http://backbonejs.org/#View-undelegateEvents

I use a method added to the Backbone.View prototype to easily clean up views:

```
Backbone.View.prototype.close = function() {
    this.undelegateEvents();
    this.remove();
}

// internal usage
this.close();

// external usage
myView.close();
```

---

**EDIT 19/07/2013**

Backbone v0.9.9 added the `.listenTo()` method to views, making it easy to unbind external events when the view is removed.

You can read more here:

- [Backbone.js - listenTo() documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo)
- [StackOverflow - Backbone 0.9.9: Difference between ListenTo and on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041042/backbone-0-9-9-difference-between-listento-and-on)