# Backbone 0.9.9: Difference between listenTo and on

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, backbone-events

I am trying to learn the new changes they did in Backbone 0.9.9.

Currently I got problems to understand the difference between `listenTo` and `on`:

**listenTo**

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: "div",

    intialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.empty();
        this.$el.append('<p>hello world</p>');
    }

});
```

**on**

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: "div",

    intialize: function() {
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.empty();
        this.$el.append('<p>hello world</p>');
    }

});
```

I have heard that `listenTo` allows with `stopListening` to unsubscribe from all events when for example the view gets removed to avoid memory leaks.

Is this the only reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Backbone js .listenTo vs .on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823746/backbone-js-listento-vs-on)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`listenTo` and `stopListening` came from the community, basically. They help to make it easier to bind and unbind events.

There's a lot of existing documentation and blog posts surrounding the idea, including stuff that I've written on the subject.

Johnny Oshika is the first person that I saw using this technique. It was originally posted as an answer to a StackOverflow question here: [Backbone.js : repopulate or recreate the view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567404/backbone-js-repopulate-or-recreate-the-view/7607853#7607853)

You can read what I've written about this, here:

- [Backbone.EventBinder: Better Event Management For Your Backbone Apps](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/10/01/backbone-eventbinder-better-event-management-for-your-backbone-apps/)
- [Zombies! RUN! (Managing Page Transitions In Backbone Apps)](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/)
- [Backbone.js And JavaScript Garbage Collection](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/03/19/backbone-js-and-javascript-garbage-collection/)

Comment: I am just learning about this too, so this is a timely question for me.  Is the recommended practice to now use listenTo for binding all events that may need to be unbound at some point during the lifecycle of the app?

Comment: It's a good question that would be good to have a straighter answer to

Comment: @ErichBSchulz agreed, though there is no reference to listenTo in the 3 blog posts hs has made, I guess @DerickBailey is saying yes, use `listenTo` over `on`.

Comment: see this, more recent post: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2013/02/06/managing-events-as-relationships-not-just-references/

Answer (score 53):

When you create a view, both `listenTo` and `on` add event handling.  However, when the view is destroyed, the `listenTo` call will [automatically remove the event handler](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/10/01/backbone-eventbinder-better-event-management-for-your-backbone-apps/).  This [prevents memory leaks](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/03/19/backbone-js-and-javascript-garbage-collection/) and zombie event listeners.

So, use `on` if you want to manage the handler yourself.  Just make sure to call `off`.  Otherwise, call `listenTo`.