# How to update data after model fetch in Handlebars template with Backbone and Marionette?

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js, marionette

Trying to have a data field in a Handlebars template update after the model that is assigned to the Marionette CompositeView is fetched, but the HTML in the page is not getting updated.

My code looks like this:

**Model:**

```
B.Page.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: function () {
        return 'my/resource/';
    },
});
```

**View:**

```
B.Page.CompositeView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: Handlebars.compile(templates.find('#my-template').html()),

    initialize: function(options) {
        _.bindAll(this);
        this.model.fetch();
    },
)};
```

**Template:**

```
<script id="my-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    Date: <span id="my-data-field">{{data}}</span>
</script>
```

I have checked the resource and it does return proper JSON with the `data` field set.  Also, the model is getting passed in to the view.

I suspect that this is due to the `render` function not getting called after the data is retrieved; however, I would like to get feedback on how it should be done.

What is a good way to do this?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: This CompositeView does have a Collection that is associated with it (which renders just fine when I trigger the appropriate event).  I purposefully left out that part of the code to avoid muddying up the problem.

Comment: Did you make sure it was re-rendering? You may need to bind the update event to the view's render method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are right, since a `CompositeView` extends from `CollectionView`, it only re-renders on collection events by default. To make it re-render on changes on your model, you could do something like this in your `CompositeView`:

```js
initialize: function(){
    this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  The actual syntax I used is `this.model.on('change', this.render)`, but it is clear that it is the same concept.

Comment: Yes, it's the same concept, but there are slight differences: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041042/backbone-0-9-9-difference-between-listento-and-on) for example.

Answer (score 1):

All Marionette views have a modelEvents object that is bound to the passed in model. So you could clean the accepted answer up slightly by doing:

```
template: Handlebars.compile(templates.find('#my-template').html()),

modelEvents: {
    'change': 'render'
}
```

rather than binding manually in initialize.